# React Apollo fetch once

Tags: react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client

Im working on simply COVID-19 tracker and i have a problem.
Is there any option in Apollo for React to fetch graphql data once per button press?

Now i have TextInput and Button but when i fetch data once i can't type another country in input because i have immediately error.

```
const Tile = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('Poland');
  const [cases, setCases] = useState(0);

  const MY_QUERY = gql`
    query getCountryStats($country: String!) {
      country(name: $country) {
        todayCases
      }
    }
  `;

  const [getCountryStats, {data, loading, error}] = useLazyQuery(MY_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      country: country,
    },
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setCases(data.country.todayCases);
    },
  });

  if (loading) return <Text>LOADING...</Text>;
  if (error) return <Text>Error!</Text>;

  return (
    <View>
      <CasesNumber>{cases}</CasesNumber>
      <FinderWrapper>
        <FinderInput
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setCountry(text);
          }}
        />
        <FinderButton
          onPress={() => {
            getCountryStats();
          }}>
          <Text>FIND</Text>
        </FinderButton>
      </FinderWrapper>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Tile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
const Tile = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('Poland');
  const [cases, setCases] = useState(0);

  let inputValue = ‘’;


  const MY_QUERY = gql`
    query getCountryStats($country: String!) {
      country(name: $country) {
        todayCases
      }
    }
  `;

  const [getCountryStats, {data, loading, error}] = useLazyQuery(MY_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      country: country,
    },
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setCases(data.country.todayCases);
    },
  });

  const onGetCountryStats = () => {
    
    setCountry(inputValue);
    getCountryStats();
  }

  if (loading) return <Text>LOADING...</Text>;
  if (error) return <Text>Error!</Text>;

  return (
    <View>
      <CasesNumber>{cases}</CasesNumber>
      <FinderWrapper>
        <FinderInput
          onChangeText={(text) => {
           inputValue = text;
          }}
        />
        <FinderButton
          onPress={() => {
           onGetCountryStats();
          }}>
          <Text>FIND</Text>
        </FinderButton>
      </FinderWrapper>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Tile;
```